# C# Dynamic Action generation

Tags: c#, code-generation

I have a C # component, which connects to a third-party system.

I am need to extend the capabilities of other system, to do this i want to add dynamic code generation to the component.

Example, I have events

```
public event Action <string> DataArrival;
public new event Action <object> OnError;
public new event Action <object> OnClose;
```

i can see this actions, from other system like

```
MyDll.Events.DataArrival(string)
MyDll.Events.OnError(object).....
```

Can i create runtime method that will dynamically create new Action?
Example

```
void CreateNewAction(string Name, TypeOfParams....)
{
    //Creating new action .
}
```

i use code in system

```
MyDll.CreateNewAction("NewEvent", typeOf(int));
```

And after this i want to see in other system

```
MyDll.Events.NewEvent(int)
```

is it possible?

Comment: `MyDll.CreateNewAction("NewEvent", typeOf(int));` runtime ... `MyDll.Events.NewEvent(int)` compiletime check... I'll vote.. no you can't.  You'll probably end up with something like: `MyDll.Events.ExecAction("NewEvent", 10);`

Comment: *, from other system like* **How?** What communication library you use? WCF? And what type of services? SOAP? REST? Made-by-yourself?

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly but there are plenty of ways to create code at runtime. But usually this is a security threat and you need to be carful.

Comment: This dll connected as Com. Service it`s 1C system.

Comment: I have a similar problem ... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617866/c-sharp-dynamic-property-assignment-action